# Code for the Harrell-Davis quantile estimator in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, statistics, outliers, quantile

We're taking a fresh look at how to review possible outliers in large data sets. We've sorted out some code for IQR and fences, MAD (Median Absolute Deviation), and Double MAD. Those three sound reasonably good at coping with series that include a lot of variabilities, but they're sensitive to asymmetry in the series. Our values are commonly skewed.

Doubled proves *less* susceptible as it splits the distribution in two and performs the MAD scoring on each half. So, points on either side of the overall median do not distort issues on the other side of the median. As I understand it, what I know comes from here:

https://eurekastatistics.com/using-the-median-absolute-deviation-to-find-outliers/

All of these estimators depend on quantiles, and it sounds like the Harrell-Davis quantile estimator improves the quality of these other methods:

https://aakinshin.net/posts/harrell-davis-double-mad-outlier-detector/

MAD, DoubleMad, and Harrell-Davis seem to be widely used in the sciences, academia, and stats generally. You can get everything in R, but we're hoping to do some outlier checking directly in Postgres. (RDS deploy, no R.)

Does this ring a bell? Has anyone seen code like this for Postgres or any other SQL idiom?

And, not to give a misimpression, I'm not a stats person and have zero ability to translate greek formulas into SQL code. But, I can do okay translating between SQL idioms and following basic concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know why people do this sort of work in R: **Because R is fantastic for this kind of work.** If anyone comes across this in the future, go get R. It's a compact, easy-to-use, easy-to-learn language with a great IDE.

If you've got a Postgres server where you can install PL/R, so much the better. PL/R is written to use the `DBI` and `RPostgreSQL` R packages to connect with Postgres. Meaning, you should be able to develop your code in RStudio, and then add the bits of wrapping required to make it run in PL/R within your Postgres server.

For outliers, I'm happy with `univOutl` (Univariate Outliers) so far, which provides 10 common, and less common, methods.